# re.sub adding a newline in python

Tags: python, xml, regex

I have the following text:

```
xml = '''
<accessibility_info>
    <accessibility role="captions" available="true" />
</accessibility_info>
<crew_member billing="top"
    <display_name>John Viscount</display_name>
</crew_member>
<products>
    <territory>GB</territory>
</products>'''
```

I need to remove the following `<crew_member>` block. This is what I am currently doing:

```
clean_xml = re.sub('<crew_member>.*</crew_member>', '', metadata_contents, 
                    flags=re.DOTALL)
```

However, it is also adding a newline:

```
<accessibility_info>
    <accessibility role="captions" available="true" />
</accessibility_info>

<products>
    <territory>GB</territory>
</products>
```

How would I change the regex to strip the newline as well, so it looks like:

```
<accessibility_info>
    <accessibility role="captions" available="true" />
</accessibility_info>
<products>
    <territory>GB</territory>
</products>'
```

Comment: Simply add `\n` to the end of your match string.

Comment: It's not that it's adding a newline, but that you're failing to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

`print re.sub('<crew_member([^\>]*)>.*</crew_member>\n', '', xml, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old but I would like to say that the new line comes actually from the method used to write the new text to the file. If I use `print()` a new line is added but if I use for example `sys.stdout.write()`, then no new line is added.